# Assigning colnames in matrix usinf "for"

Tags: r, matrix

I have n factors and made n(n-1)/2 combinations of these factors as the columns in a matrix. Now,I want to assign the names of the columns as each name show me which two factors combined. This is what I wrote. But the error is that "length of dinames is not equal to array content". What would you suggest?

```
for (i in 1:ncol(X_ok)) { 
for (j in i:ncol(X_ok)) {
if(i == j){
next
}
   colnames(out_or)<-paste0(colnames(X_ok)[i],colnames(X_ok)[j], sep='*')
  }
}
```

Comment: out-or file has teh same number of columns as calculated by n(n-1)/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate quite easily all the possible combinations of `X_ok` without using a `for` loop:

```
X_ok <- LETTERS[1:5] # as an example

combinations <- combn(X_ok, 2)
```

Then you can concatenate the output by column to get the new names separated by `*`:

```
colnames(out_or) <- apply(combinations, 2, paste, collapse = "*")
```

Comment: You can just replace `collapse = ""` by `collapse = "*"` to separate the names with `*`.

Comment: Thank you so much Alex. Can you tell me what is 2? You saved me. It worked.. Also can I ask another question?

Comment: I had a matrix  with 2029 rows (individuals) and 1129 columns (SNP markers). all the matrix are 1 or 0. I want to calculate all combinations of the snps for each individual as  0*1=1 and 1*0=1 and 0*0=0 and 1*1=0. I wrote by teh script by for. But is it possible to write with combn?

Comment: If you look at the help of the function (`?combn`), you will see that the second argument `m` is the number of elements to choose from the vector. Here, 2 means that we get all the possible combinations of 2 elements from the vector (AA, AB, etc.).
Regarding your second question, you could avoid for loops as well but as this problem is slightly different, I would advise to ask a new question. Please consider reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to ask a good question and help people reproducing your problem.

Comment: Also, please consider upvoting and accepting my answer if you found it useful!

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach using crossing() from tidyverse.

```
X_ok <- letters[1:5]

library(tidyverse)
crossing(X_ok, X_ok) %>% 
  mutate(column_names = paste(X_ok, Y_ok, sep='*')) %>% 
  select(column_names) -> cc
names(out_or) <- cc$column_names
```

Might be slightly easier to read if you are not used to apply() syntax.